# SQL: Get Count of Strings Occurence in 2 Tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, each contain a column called symbol.

I want to query both tables and get a list containing each symbol and the number of times it occurred in each table like the example below:

```
Symbol | Count
a | 2
b | 6
c | 7
```

Below is what I currently have in terms of the query but I am not getting the result I want.

```
SELECT one.symbol, COUNT(*) FROM one
JOIN two GROUP BY one.symbol,two.symbol;
```

This ends up listing all of the symbols multiple times, and the count is very large.

I have also tried:

```
SELECT orders.symbol, COUNT(orders.symbol) FROM orders
JOIN executions GROUP BY orders.symbol;
```

This lists each symbol once like I want, however it only shows the count from one table twice (example count is 1, and it shows 11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat the two tables as one table by combining them in an inner subquery, then sum the counts outside...

```
SELECT 
    symbol,
    SUM(symbol_count)
FROM (
    SELECT
        symbol,
        COUNT(symbol) as symbol_count
    FROM
        table_one
    GROUP BY
        symbol

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        symbol,
        COUNT(symbol) as symbol_count
    FROM
        table_two
    GROUP BY
        symbol
) AS symbol_counts
GROUP BY
    symbol
```

UPDATE:
To answer the question posed in the comments, to get the counts side by side:

```
SELECT
    symbol,
    COALESCE(table_one.symbol_count, 0) AS table_one_count,
    COALESCE(table_two.symbol_count, 0) AS table_two_count
FROM
    (SELECT
        symbol,
        COUNT(symbol) as symbol_count
     FROM
        table_one
     GROUP BY
        symbol) AS table_one
   FULL JOIN
    (SELECT
        symbol,
        COUNT(symbol) as symbol_count
     FROM
        table_two
     GROUP BY
        symbol) AS table_two
   ON table_one.symbol = table_two.symbol
```

`FULL JOIN` ensures that if either table is missing one of the symbols it is still picked up. `COALESCE` will ensure that if one of them is missing (returns NULL, it will be replaced with a zero.

Comment: Why pre-count? Haven't tested, but this should work as well: `SELECT symbol, COUNT(*) AS num FROM (SELECT symbol FROM one UNION SELECT symbol FROM two) GROUP BY symbol` (though I am sleepy and might be missing something)

Comment: Alan's solution works. Amadan, yours lists all the symbols but the count for each one is 1.

Comment: Hey Alan, If I wanted to see the count in each table so there were 3 columns, how would I go about that? Here is what I currently have and I am not getting any luck. `SELECT 
    symbol,
    SUM(t1_count),
    SUM(t2_count)
FROM (
    SELECT
        symbol,
        COUNT(symbol) as t1_count
    FROM
        table_one
    GROUP BY
        symbol

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        symbol,
        COUNT(symbol) as t2_count
    FROM
        table_two
    GROUP BY
        symbol
) AS t1_counts, t2_counts
GROUP BY
    symbol`

Comment: Thanks Alan, you are a true life saver!

Comment: The trick is to think about your data as SETS, regardless of how the tables store the data. If you need a different set, construct one and work on that constructed set. That's how you solve for these sort of problems generically.